# Xcode project keeps resolving swift package even though its been removed from project

Tags: swift, xcode, swift-package-manager

I've been searching for a few days with no luck on how to fix this. Essentially, I have a tvOS project which was using a package (https://swiftpackageregistry.com/lorenzofiamingo/swiftui-cached-async-image to be precise).

I have since removed this package from the project as have no use for it anymore. However, whenever I use xcodebuild to run tests/create an archive/etc, the output log still says that it is resolving and fetching the package. This is causing issues later on when building on jenkins so need the package to go.

## Console Output

```
xcodebuild test -workspace project.xcworkspace -scheme "scheme" -destination "platform=tvOS Simulator,name=Apple TV"

User defaults from command line:
    IDEPackageSupportUseBuiltinSCM = YES

Resolve Package Graph

// why is this still being resolved when it has been removed from the project??
Resolved source packages:
  swiftui-cached-async-image: https://github.com/lorenzofiamingo/swiftui-cached-async-image @ main


note: Using new build system
note: Planning
Analyze workspace
...
```

I have done the following:

- Removed the package from the project under package dependencies.
- Deleted the builds inside DerivedData.
- Deleted the package.resolved file.

The last two files keep getting replaced each time I open xcode as it realises the file is gone and does a fetch for the package.

Any ideas on what I could be missing? I'm assuming xcode has some super secret reference to it that I cant find. Surely it should be possible to just have the package removed as if it was never there in the first place.

Thanks